# Can't resolve 'axios' in 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\pics\src\components'

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am having trouble importing the axios npm module. I have reinstalled npm, and I have tried `npm install axios`, but I am still getting this error.

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar'

class App extends React.Component{
    onSearchSubmit(term){
       axios.get('https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos',{
           params : {query : term},
           headers:{
            Authorization: 'Client-ID 70822bb6597a62eb06e224569a56f353f13fc6578a677abb1e8ad1dce0993396'
           }

       });
    }
    render(){

        return (
            <div className='ui container' style={{marginTop : '30px'}}>
                <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default App;
```

and this is my error

```
./src/components/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'axios' in 
'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\pics\src\components'
```

Comment: Use 'npm list axios' inside your project root and check if it is installed.

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: I said to check the result of npm list axios and verify if axios is installed. It was not the solution to your problem rather a step 1 to check what the issue is.

Comment: Can you attach the output of 'npm list axios'? Will be more helpful in debugging

Comment: pics@0.1.0 C:\Users\HP\Desktop\pics
`-- axios@0.18.0

Answer (score 3):

Looks like axios isn't installed.  Try npm install --save axios.  Then double check your import statement.  It should be "import axios from 'axios'"

this solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you've successfully installed axios, it may just be that you need to stop your process and run npm start again.